# Set LineChart(javafx) style to a child element

Tags: java, css, javafx

I want to use 2 objects  with one line on each. [image: LineChart]

I set color like this `.chart-series-line {-fx-stroke: #ff0099; }` and lines changed both. But color on the lines must be different. How can i changed lines separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a CSS id on each line chart, e.g.

```
LineChart leftChart = new LineChart(...);
leftChart.setId("left");

LineChart rightChart = new LineChart(...);
rightChart.setId("right");
```

(or if you are using FXML

```
<LineChart id="left" ... >
```

etc)

and then in your css file you can do

```
#left .chart-series-line {-fx-stroke: #ff0099; }
```

etc.